# Recreating db Snapshots on scheduled basis

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am new to db world. I have to create a job that will drop the db snapshots and recreate it on daily basis. But I was wondering how can I validate once the snapshots is setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLAgent to accomplish this: [Creation & Deletion of Database Snapshot by SQL Agent Job](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Creation-Deletion-of-68d2b9aa)

```
 --Step 1 :- 
DECLARE @CREATE_SS VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @DT VARCHAR(100) 
SET @DT = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),120),’-‘,’_’),’ ‘,’_’),':’,’_’) 
SET @CREATE_SS = 
‘CREATE DATABASE TEST_’+@DT+’ ON 
( NAME = TEST, FILENAME = 
”C:\TEST_’+@DT+’.SS” ) 
AS SNAPSHOT OF TEST’ 
EXEC (@CREATE_SS) 

--Step 2 :- 
IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE SOURCE_DATABASE_ID = DB_ID(‘TEST’))>1 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @DROP_SS VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @SS_NAME VARCHAR(100) 
SELECT TOP 1 @SS_NAME = NAME FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE SOURCE_DATABASE_ID = DB_ID(‘TEST’) 
ORDER BY CREATE_DATE ASC 
SET @DROP_SS = ‘DROP DATABASE ‘+ @SS_NAME 
EXEC (@DROP_SS) 
END
```

For the validation part,you can use below query..

```
if exists(
SELECT  *  FROM   sys.databases   WHERE    name = 'somename' 
    AND source_database_id IS NOT NULL)
begin
print 'database snapshot created'
end
```